# Error pointing to non-existent file when running Node.js app locally

Tags: node.js

I was just sent the files for a Node.js app (which is working without issues online) and I'm trying to set it up on my Windows machine.

I have Node server running, but I'm stuck trying to actually load the app. I can navigate to the directory with the Node command prompt, and there's an `app.js` (plus folders like `config`, `components` etc) in there which I've been trying to run, but I am getting the following error:

```
D:\my-directory\game-master>node app.js
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\posao\aktivni projekti\smart rebellion\game-master
\app.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

The thing is, there is no file titled `module.js` in the directory. I presume it's a built in Node.js file, but then how do I troubleshoot this?

My best reading of the error is that there should be a `config.js` file somewhere, but that doesn't make sense because these same exact files work with no hickups on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `require('./config')`, where `config` is a directory, the file `./config/index.js` should exist.

You can't `require('config')` however, because node.js will try to find it in `node_modules`.

Check out [node.js modules documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) where the `require` algorithm is well explained.

Comment: There's a config directory, but the only file inside it is `default.js`, not `index.js`. If file name is the problem, any idea how come it works on the other server?